# List of single type cannot be assigned to list of union type

Tags: python, typing, pylance, pyright

I wrote a python code like below

```
class A:
    pass

class B:
    pass

class C:
    pass

from typing import TypeVar, Union, Type, Optional, List

test = TypeVar("test", bound=A)

def wow(w: Optional[List[Union[Type["test"], Type[C]]]]):
    pass

wow([A]);
```

[image: errorhighlighted]

Pylance highlights the line `wow([A])` as an error, so I wonder if I wrote the wrong code or if Pylance worked wrong.

[image]

when i remove Union part, then it worked well, so i thought there's no reason that the code should be highlighted just because i added Union. But I may be completely mistaken, so please teach me.

below is the error message that I got

```
Argument of type "list[Type[A]]" cannot be assigned to parameter "w" of type "List[Type[test@wow] | Type[C]] | None" in function "wow"
  Type "list[Type[A]]" cannot be assigned to type "List[Type[test@wow] | Type[C]] | None"
    "list[Type[A]]" is incompatible with "List[Type[test@wow] | Type[C]]"
      TypeVar "_T@list" is invariant
        Type "Type[A]" cannot be assigned to type "Type[test@wow] | Type[C]"
          "Type[A]" is incompatible with "Type[C]"
          Type "Type[A]" cannot be assigned to type "Type[C]"
    Type cannot be assigned to type "None"
```

Comment: there wasn't any need to post a question regarding a vs code extension thing as you could have simply hovered over the error to see what it was referring to.

Comment: @Jyotirmay 
The error message said `Type[A] cannot be assigned to type "Type[test@wow] | Type[C]`, but i thought it can be. What i want to know is if my code was wrong, or the extension malfunctioned. I added the error message that i got when i hovered on the code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is actually almost exactly an example from pyright's type concepts docs in their section about generic types: https://github.com/microsoft/pyright/blob/main/docs/type-concepts.md#generic-types

Essentially, because lists are mutable types, you can't assign a `list[Type[A]]` to be a `list[Type[test@wow] | Type[C]]` because if you add a `Type[C]` to your `list[Type[A]]`, it would no longer be a `list[Type[A]]`. If you declare `w` to be the immutable `Sequence` type instead, thereby promising not to modify `w`, you can get rid of your type error.